# UDP client error: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, sockets, tcpclient, python-sockets

I have a simple TCP client code:

```py
from socket import *

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
udpCliScok = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    data = input('>')
    if not data:
        break
    udpCliScok.sendto(data.encode('UTF-8'),ADDR)
    data , addr = udpCliScok.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data)

udpCliScok.close()
```

but after I run it and input any text, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python\WSGI\Core Python Networking\tsUclnt.py", line 19, in <module>
    data , addr = udpCliScok.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I have tried different ports but still get the same error

Comment: Is there anything listening on this port?

Comment: @jurez Not that I know of

Comment: @Pexicade: "I have a simple TCP client code: ...."* - that's not a TCP client. It is a UDP client. Also, if you don't know if there is some server you are connecting to, then there likely is no server. But you cannot receive any data from a non-existing server. I propose the question as not reproducible, i.e. once there is a server it should actually work.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeah it's actually UDP, my bad. So how can I create a server so that I can  receive data from?

Comment: @Pexicade: *"...  how can I create a server so that I can receive data from?"* - different question and too broad. But just for testing you could use existing applications like netcat.